# Проблемы с парсингом python

Tags: python, selenium

В парсерах я новичок. Может быть я чего то не понимаю, но в сети ответа так и не нашёл.
Пытаюсь спарсить, ну например, инвентарь стим, стандартный набор: selenium/requests_html, которые умеют парсить с js, и BeautifulSoup. Но в итоге я получаю не полную страницу, которую вижу в браузере. Ок, пытаюсь разобраться, смотрим код страницы, Network -> XHR, ошибка, инициатор jquery-1.11.1.min.js... На сколько я понял, он запрашивает json, адрес понятен, так же могу этот json спарсить (https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198113737845/440/2?l=russian&count=75).
Ну а дальше то что? Как мне получить те данные, что я вижу в браузере, но которые не получаю через парсер? Я понимаю, что та информация, что мне нужна, уже есть в этом json, и с помощью регулярок я без проблем могу их от туда достать. Но мне нужна именно полноценная html страница, тк в json файле нет информации, например, о кол-ве одинаковых вещей.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

link = 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198113737845/inventory/#252490'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='E:\\steam_pars\\chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')  # отключаем режим Webdriver

try:
    driver.get(url=link)
    time.sleep(10)
    steam_html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(steam_html, 'lxml')
    block = soup.find('h1', class_='hover_item_name')
    with open('test.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:  # сохраняем страницу на всякий случай
        file.write(steam_html)
    print('*' * 10)
    print(block.text)  # естественно пустая строка 
    print('*' * 10)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос:

```
html_with_all_content = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
```